# Maxima problem related to physics

Tags: calculus, optimization

I was solving a physics question, and in the end, I got it down to 'finding the relation between H and h such that the following expression is maximized':

$\sqrt{H-h} + \sqrt{h}$.

Can you please guide me?
 I know it sounds simple, but the derivative was becoming very tedious to solve (equate to zero).

Comment: We can operate mechanically. The derivative is 
$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(H-h)^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{h^{1/2}}$.
Set the derivative equal to $0$. We get
$\frac{1}{(H-h)^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{h^{1/2}}$.
Manipulation gives the equivalent equation $(H-h)^{1/2}=h^{1/2}$. Squaring both sides gives $H-h=h$, so $h=H/2$.

Comment: but where is the dh/dH term from implicit differentiation?

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, it is mentioned how to differentiate and set the derivative equal to $0$. We look at the problem another way.

Maximizing $\sqrt{H-h}+\sqrt{h}$ is equivalent to maximizing $(\sqrt{H-h}+\sqrt{h})^2$. This square turns out to be $H+2\sqrt{H-h}\sqrt{h}$.

Since $H$ is fixed, we want to maximize $2\sqrt{H-h}\sqrt{h}$, or equivalently we want to maximize its square $4hH-4h^2$, under the restriction $0\le h\le H$.

Now if we wish we can use differentiation. The derivative is $4H-8h$, which is $0$ at $h=\frac{H}{2}$.  It is not hard to verify that we indeed have  have a maximum, since the endpoints $h=0$ and $h=H$ give minima.

**Remark:** Instead of using calculus, we can complete the square, or use properties of the parabola $y=4Hx-4x^2$. There are several other ways.

Comment: Instead of using calculus, we can use this theorem: "Let $x_1$, $x_2$ be two variables having a constant sum $S$, then $x_1x_2$ has a maximum for $x_1=x_2=\frac{S}{2}$". Just take $x_1=h$ and $x_2=H-h$, you'll get $h=\frac{H}{2}$

Comment: why are you guys forgetting the fact that implicit differentiation is being used, and we must write the dh/dH term?? With respect to what are you differentiating it?

Comment: What $H$ is has not been defined. It is reasonable to treat it as a constant. If it happens not to be, OP can say so.